# How to get taskid that "waitForQualityGate()" is going to check for?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sonarqube

I apologize for duplicating my post from sonarsource, but sometimes this gets a different audience.

We’re using SonarQube 7.9.2.

Our Jenkins builds use the pipeline steps “withSonarQubeEnv” and “waitForQualityGate”, and in between we use “mvn sonar:sonar” to run the scan. At the end of the latter, it prints the task id it’s going to be waiting for in “waitForQualityGate”. It also shows that task id in the results of that step.

What WebApi call(s) can I perform in between “mvn sonar:sonar” and “waitForQualityGate” that will let me store into a variable the task id that is going to be polled for? I know the project key at that point. I’ve inspected all of the environment variables in scope at that point.

I know how to find the WebApi documentation, and I’ve scanned through what I think are the relevant operations, but I can’t figure out which operation I need for this particular “task”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the mvn sonar:sonar, report-task.txt will be created in the workspace folder .scannerwork.

[image]

You will get the **ceTaskUrl** and **ceTaskId** in report-task.txt. Now, you can use that ceTaskUrl to get the **analysisId**.

You can use the below api to get the quality gate status using analysisId.

https://localhost:9000/sonarqube/api/qualitygates/project_status?analysisId=$ANALYSIS_ID"

Comment: Actually, the location of the file depends on the tool that was used to generate it.  The "mvn sonar:sonar" task defaults to "target/sonar". This location is controlled by the "sonar.scanner.metadataFilePath" property.

Comment: Great. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr couldn't find this info in sonar doc, thanks